# What is the difference between 'url' and 'path' in symfony2.3

Tags: symfony, twig

The document said

```
{# src/Acme/ArticleBundle/Resources/views/Article/recentList.html.twig #}
{% for article in articles %}
    <a href="{{ path('article_show', {'slug': article.slug}) }}">
        {{ article.title }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

also, can use 'url' like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('_welcome') }}">Home</a>
```

it confused me what is the difference between using 'url' and 'path'?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

They are very similar.

### path()

Generates a relative/absolute **path** :

`path('contact')` will generate `/contact`

### url()

Generates a scheme-relative/absolute **url**, ie domain + path

`url('contact')` will generate `http://example.org/contact`

The url() style is useful when using **cross-domain ajax** or generating **emails**, because the hostname won't be the same.

Take a look at the code https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php for more information

Answer (score 5):

url Twig function generates absolute path
path Twig function generates / related url

Example we have http://sf2sandbox.local with AcmeDemoBundle

```
{{ path('_welcome') }} produce /
{{ url('_welcome') }} produce http://sf2sandbox.local/
```

Comment: Did you mean *relative* path?